# Stored Procedure updates where last modified equals getdate but it also updates getdate trigger

Tags: sql-server

I have a trigger that updates a `datetime` column called `lastmodified`.

I also have a scheduled job running a stored procedure that updates a table

```
where lastmodified = getdate()
```

This stored procedure is triggering the last modified trigger, meaning it's updating every row each time it runs.

Any idea how to get around this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about disabling the Trigger before the start of the UPDATE statement and enabling it just after the UPDATE?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Your_Procedure] 
AS
BEGIN
   EXEC('DISABLE TRIGGER YourTrigger ON YourTable'); 
   UPDATE YourTable
   SET YourColumn = some_value
   where lastmodified = getdate()
   EXEC('ENABLE TRIGGER YourTrigger ON YourTable');
END;
```

Comment: Great idea! Thank you!